# How to convert a string to map in terraform 0.11?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How can a string can be converted to map in terraform **0.11.1**?

```
variable "custom_aws_tag" {
   default = "key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value3"
}
```

I would like to get key value pair from the user in the above string format and assign the same to AWS tag. Terraform's resource "aws_instance" accepts tags in map format.

```
resource "aws_instance" "app" {
   tags = "${merge(
     "${var.custom_aws_tag}",   <=== Needs to be interpolate to map before merging
     map(
       "app_name","acme",
       "env", "prod",
     )
   )}"
}
```

I would like to convert above string variable (custom_aws_tag) to map before merging it with the existing tags.

As a result, below are the tags needs to be configured on EC2 instances

```
key1:value1
key2:value2
key3:value3
app_name:acme
env:prod
```